# Scatterplot with line overlaid, R

Tags: r, plot

I've search extensively on SO, but am having trouble locating a response.

I want to create a scatterplot of X and Y using base graphics in R.
Then, I want to overlay a line of X and Z.  I also want the chart colored by a fourth variable.

Here's the code I've written:

```
par(mfrow=c(2, 1))
par(mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1))
plot(bind23$datetime, bind23$log, type= "n")
points(bind23$datetime[bind23$HourlyPrecipIn ==0], bind23$log[bind23$HourlyPrecipIn ==0], col= "blue", pch=1)
points(bind23$datetime[bind23$HourlyPrecipIn > 0],     bind23$log[bind23$HourlyPrecipIn > 0], col= "red", pch=1)
lines(bind23$dailyrainin, type='l', col="black")
legend("topleft", c("Below mean", "Above Mean"), col= c("blue", "red"), pch=c(1, 1))
```

The plot works, along with the colored points, but the overlaid line does not.  Can anyone offer any recommendations...I'm guessing my lines command is not sufficient.  Thanks!

Comment: You say "it doesn't work" but that could mean almost anything. A reproducible example would help a lot.

Comment: If you can add some lines to generate toy data that matches the structure of the data you're using in your code, that would really help. Without a reproducible example, it's hard to be sure that a proposed solution will work.

Comment: I think you need to include an x variable in your call to `lines()`, so something like `with(bind23, lines(datetime, dailyrainin, col="black"))`. Also, you can do all your points in one go and make the color conditional instead, like `with(bind23, points(datetime, log, col = ifelse(HourlyPrecipIn==0, "blue", "red"), pch = 1))`.

Comment: You have only an `x` variable in `lines()`. Based on your other plots, it looks like you'd want `x = bind23$datetime` and `y = bind23$dailyrainin` in `lines()`. You also do not need `type='l'` for `lines` because it is a line by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a reproducible example, I can't be sure this works, but from your code and your comments, I think it will. As a couple of us noted in comments, the problem with your call to `lines()` is the absence of a second variable. If you only feed it one variable, it will assume that's an x value, not a y value. Also, you can shrink your calls to `points()` to a single line by using `ifelse()` to make the color conditional on the value of another variable.

```
par(mai = c(1,1,1,1))
with(bind23, plot(datetime, log, type= "n")
with(bind23, points(datetime, log, col = ifelse(HourlyPrecipIn==0, "blue", "red"), pch = 1))
with(bind23, lines(datetime, dailyrainin, col="black"))
legend("topleft", c("Below mean", "Above Mean"), col= c("blue", "red"), pch=c(1, 1))
```

I left off the `par(mfrow=c(2,1))` line at the start because you've only created one plot here. Maybe there's another to come?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that everything but the line worked in the initial code.  With your addition of the x=datetime in the lines statement, it works now.  Thanks!